# Two pairs of AirPods, single charging case

Tags: airpods

I lost my AirPods (original, wired) charging case recently. Since I use these a lot during the day for work calls I'm frequently hitting periods where they are dead or I'm continuing with only one in my ear while trying to charge the second one up and swapping like that back and forth. So it would be kind of ideal to have two pairs, but what I'm curious of is if I bought a 2nd full pair of AirPods (with case), could I then use the new case to keep both new and old headphones charged? Will this cause any issues in terms of connecting them to my devices/syncing?

Comment: @NimeshNeema It's the other way round here, but it doesn't actually matter :-)